# Gem install (of any gem) results in error on ubuntu 12.04 32 bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I recently  installed rvm with ruby 2.1.1. Its the only ruby that i have installed on my machine - running ubuntu linux 12.04 32 bit.

```
john@ubuntu:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.1 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

john@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [i686-linux]
```

any gem install results in the errors below.

gem install rmagick

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.gem.20140807-31794-1kcf5mf

Gem files will remain installed in /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/bcrypt-3.1.7/gem_make.out
 (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.4/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./.gem.20140807-31794-uyv7bu

Gem files will remain installed in /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/bcrypt-3.1.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/bcrypt-3.1.7/gem_make.out
 (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.3
```

I checked my rvm notes and nothing weird sticks out. I had a WARNING about adding a source to my .bash_profile file which i did. that file now looks like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && source "~/.profile"
```

Also, I get the errors documeneted above when i run "rails s" for my rails project.

Any pointers here? Need to complete some work and this is a REAL blocker.

Thanks!

Comment: how did you install RVM? what are the permissions on .rvm and the directories in question.  My guess is that the perms on it are set wrong, or you used sudo at somepoint and root owns parts of your install.   try doing a `chown -r john .rvm `  and see if that fixes it,   else `rvm implode` and start over might be eaiser

Comment: getting thiss: chown: invalid option -- 'r'
yeah i think i did use sudo at some point.

Comment: sorry `chown -R ` as opposed to `chown -r` and don't use `sudo` with RVM

Comment: you might need to use sudo to do it, based on the what the permissions actually are so `sudo chown -R john:john .rvm` assuming your group name is john as well

Answer (score 0):

Trying using this code to make rvm reload rubygems:

```
rvm rubygems current
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you are missing a dependency:

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: Would this be specific to installing rmagick? i did this earlier and im still getting the error i reported in the question. Note that the error happens on any gem install. so for example "gem install rails" gives the same error.